# How to move html code from a component function into an html/heex partial?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

Let's say I have something like this:

```
    defmodule MyAppWeb.Live.PostComponents do
      use Phoenix.Component
      use Phoenix.HTML

      def card(assigns) do
        ~H"""
        <div class="row ....">
            <nav class="......"></nav>
            <%= live_redirect "...", to: @content.slug, class: "stretched-link" %>
          <%= if  do %>
            blah-blah-blah-blah-blah-blah
          <% end %>
        </div>
        """
      end
```

How to move this code into an html or *.heex file to then call render(....) somehow?
The end result must remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed `*.html.heex` files into function components with `embed_templates/1` [see LiveView docs here](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.Component.html#module-embedding-external-template-files).

The template code can be put into a `card.html.heex` file (by convention the template files can be moved to separate directory near your module, e.g. `/pages/card.html.heex`. In your `MyAppWeb.Live.PostComponents` you then call `embed_templates/1` on module level with the path to the template folder as an argument and `MyAppWeb.Live.PostComponents` will have a function component `card` defined.

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.Live.PostComponents do
  use Phoenix.Component

  embed_templates "pages/*.html.heex"
end
```

```
# somewhere else in another template or render function
~H"""
...
<MyAppWeb.Live.PostComponents.card ... >
  ...
<./MyAppWeb.Live.PostComponents.card>
...
"""
```

For more information on declarative assigns of function components embedded like this see the [`embed_templates/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.Component.html#embed_templates/1) documentation.

Comment: what do you mean by `...template of render function`? What `render` function?

Comment: Oh sorry, it was a typo. Should be `template or render function`, fixed it in the answer.
I mean, that the function component defined by using `embed_templates` can then be used either in another template or e.g. a render function of a LiveView.

Comment: Ok... I let myself to forgive you